# I have to make a tweet tester in java, but can't figure out how to count the amount of times a character shows up in the tweet

Tags: java, string, tweets

Alright, so for a class I am taking I have to make a program that tests tweets. It asks you to input a tweet, then tells you if the tweet is valid (less than 140 characters), tells you the amount of mentions (indicated by the character @) and the number of hashtags (indicated by a #), and tells you whether or not it is a retweet (if it contains "RT:" it is considered a retweet).

I can tell whether it is a valid tweet and can tell if it is a retweet (I coded it so that if the index of "RT:" is greater than or equal to 0, it says it is a retweet), but can't figure out how to count the number of @ and # in the string the user enters. I know how to find the index, but am having trouble finding out where to go from there. I don't know what to do as a next course of action. Is there a way to count the amount of a certain character in a string?

I know what the code is currently doing, outputting the index of the first time the character shows up, but I am lost on what else I could do. I thought that maybe I could truncate every letter before and including the @ and use a loop to count the amount of times that I get an index for @, then do the same for the #, but I don't know how to truncate every letter before and including a certain character. Or is there a better option? Any help is appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math; 
public class Main {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a tweet:");
String s = scan.nextLine();
int length = s.length();

if(length > 140)
  System.out.println("Excess Characters: " + ( length - 140));
else{


  System.out.println("Length Correct");
  int at = s.indexOf('@');
  System.out.println("Number of Mentions: " + (at));
  int hash = s.indexOf('#');
  System.out.println("Number of Hashtags: " + (hash));
  if (s.indexOf("RT:") >=0)
    System.out.println("The input was a retweet.");
  else
    System.out.println("The input was not a retweet.");




}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

.indexOf will return the index of that character in your String.
That might not be the best approach to resolve your problem.
You could do something like this :

```
for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
   if(s.charAt(i) == '#') {
     count++; //or whatever mechanism you want to keep track of those chars.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by implementing a simple counting method:

```
public int charCount(char c, String tweet) {
   int count = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < tweet.length()) {
      if(tweet.charAt(i) == c) count++;
   }

   return count;
}
```

With this, you can count the number of times a character appears in a tweet.

```
  System.out.println("Length Correct");
  int at = charCount('@', s);
  System.out.println("Number of Mentions: " + at);
  int hash = charCount('#', s);
  System.out.println("Number of Hashtags: " + hash);
  if (s.indexOf("RT:") >= 0)
    System.out.println("The input was a retweet.");
  else
    System.out.println("The input was not a retweet.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving slightly on Caleb's answer:

Since you know which two characters you need to count, '@' and '#,' you can have a counter for each and just iterate over the tweet once. Then you just check if a character is one you're looking for, and if it is, the counter is incremented!

```
int mentions = 0;
int hashtags = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if(s.charAt(i) == '@') {
        mentions++;
    } else if(s.charAt(i) == '#') {
        hashtags++;
    }
}
```

Now `mentions` and `hashtags` should have the countes of @'s and #'s respectively.